# Is there any way to set OnLongClickListener on navigation drawer toggle?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, toolbar, material-ui, onlongclicklistener

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
toggle.syncState();

toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        //Do Something
    }

});
```

I know that I can set OnClickListener on navigation drawer toggle like this, but is there any way to set OnLongClickListner on drawer toggle?

Comment: This will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35720845/5167909

Comment: I suspect there is no long press click listener for toolbar

Comment: @FaysalAhmed What I found in your link was for toggle button, not drawer toggle. ActionBarToggle is not a view I guess. Should I put a menu item on the toolbar and make it act like a drawer toggle?

Comment: @vikaskumar I guess so :c